# linkage through mapped php pages from menu

Tags: php, hyperlink

To try to map up all the pages, I've made a couple of maps called products and similar naming.

However when I go through a link with, for example, `product/xxx.php` and press the same link within the menu at that page I've entered, I get an adding of `products/products/xxx.php`, which break the link.

How do you avoid or correct these sort of linkages?

so for example I have my main menu inside a php file called menu.php which I include in the index.php by php include

a snip of the main menu php is

```
 <div class="menuBar">

  <ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="Products/xxx.php" class="drop">xxx</a>

  <div class="dropdown_unit">

 <!-- Header -->
 <div class="unitSizer">
 <h4><a href="Products/xxx.php">xxx</a></h4>
 </div> <!-- END Header -->
```

and it is placed within a div at the index.php 
like this:

```
    <div class="menuBar">

     <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>

      </div> <!-- END menuBarDental -->
```

this is just 1 part of the menu but it looks the same overall inside the menu.php
the problem here is that it seems by include this php file into the index.php and generating
the links inside the menu it keeps adding instances of the links.

Comment: Well, to answer you directly, to avoid such issues one codes in such a way to ensure such issues are not introduced. If you need assistance with *your* code, we'd need to see it (otherwise we cannot possibly know what you have done and why it's doing what you say).

Comment: If you mean the website at least a tiny bit seriously, look into some framework (such as Laravel), it will make it a lot more elegant and functional.